# Generate the list of tests that pytest would have ran?

Tags: pytest

We are interested in load balancing our pytests across many servers. To accomplish this we want to generate a list of the tests that py.test would have ran but not actually run the tests. We will then feed this list into a work queue. Is there any way in py.test to generate such a report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `--collect-only` is what you're looking for?

Comment: While this is certainly a correct answer, maybe looking at pytest-xdist is a much simpler solution to the original problem of distributing the tests?